# Regarding validaton in tabs in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

I am having 3 tabs, and these 3 tabs have common submit and cancel button.When user clicks on submit button,it should automatically switch to tab on which the validation has fired,how can I achieve this functionality with below code 
Partial View : Service.cs.html

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document.body).ready(function () {

        getService("Test1");
    });

    function getService(serviceMenuId) {
        if (serviceMenuId != undefined && serviceMenuId != '') {
            jQuery("div#menubar li").each(function () {
                var $li = jQuery(this);
                $li.removeClass('sel');
            });
            document.getElementById(serviceMenuId).className = "sel";
        }

        $('div#Test1').hide();
        $('div#Test2').hide();
        $('div#Test3').hide();

        $("div#" + serviceMenuId).show();
    }
</script>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <div id="Test1" style="position:relative">@{Html.RenderPartial("Test1", Model);}</div>
    <div id="Test2" style="position:relative">@{Html.RenderPartial("Test2", Model);}</div>
    <div id="Test3" style="position:relative">@{Html.RenderPartial("Test3", Model);}</div>

    <div id="saveCancelButton" class="as-ext-form-button-div" style="margin-top: 20px;">
        <button title="Click here to save" id="saveData" type="submit"   onclick="return attributesValid();">Save</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;

    </div>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure it will help, but you may try to use focus on invalid data:

```
$("#saveData").click(function() {
        if ($("form").valid())
{ 
              alert("Valid!");
}
        else
{
              validator.focusInvalid();
}

        return false;
  });
```